# winform textbox binding from multiple sources for viewing, editing

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have created a databinding treeview which binds with multiple tables and display hierarchical data. I stole much of the mechanism from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/dbTree.aspx if it interests you.

I first merge(outer join) all the datatables into a big datatable, then databind the treeview and bunch of textboxes to the big table. User can click on a node in the treeview and see corresponding info in the textboxes. So viewing part is nice.

Now coming to updating, deleting, adding info via textboxes entries, is there a way the user can make changes via the textboxes, and immediately reflected in the big table and individual tables ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are joining information in a kind of view and I understand that this view is stored in memory while you fill your tree. So, if you do any kind of change in the data inside the tables that composes your view, you must reload it.

If you are working with an web app, it is going to be something natural, because each user interaction will do a new request to create you view.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I am doing right now, i.e. reload everything everytime something is changed, and for that I have to add a button for each table, which I don't really like....

Comment: @user570185, I don't know exactly how your solution behaves, but I believe there are better solutions than adding a new button just for reload information in case of changes... you could use an event handler to deal with changes and do the reload automatically

Comment: I have quite a few boxes, I can add event handlers when text is changed, that will be a lot of event handlers and a lot of updates to the datatables, is this what everybody does ? it seems to me like an overkill, coz 1 datatable have lots of fields, and just one field change will trigger datatable change, is there a way to avoid that ?